# Get file details without input tag using full path from filesystem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to obtain the details of files that I previewed in my webpage using the `<embed src = "full path"` I only found the input tag way which doesn't match what I want.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body" onclick="return myFunction1('0')">Capture.PNG</div>
<div class="panel-body" onclick="return myFunction1('1')">Sample2.PDF</div>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction1(index) {
    var parent = $('#demo').parent();
    if (index == '0') {
      $('#demo').remove();
    $("h2").append("<embed id = 'demo' src='http://localhost:8080//Part2/Capture.PNG' width='500' height='600'>");
    }
    if (index == '1') {
      $('#demo').remove();
    $("h2").append("<embed id = 'demo' src='http://localhost:8080//Part2/sample2.pdf' width='500' height='600'>");
    }
  }
</script>
```

So basically, after I click on Capture.PNG/sample2.pdf a preview space is displayed in the page showing the content of the file.

Comment: Question doesn't explain what you are expecting. What 'input' tag are you referring to?

Comment: @nazim I'm referring to the embed tad in the append function, the way I'm previewing the files is through the `<embed src =..` because usually people do it through the `<input ` where you need to first attach the file

Comment: Oh I now see that the question title asks for *full path from filesystem*... However your code implies the use of a local-server. Which one i correct? Below solution won't work on `file://` scheme (a.k.a *filesystem*) but will on localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get all the info available in the File API through an Ajax request, but you would obviously need your file to be hosted on a cross-origin compliant domain:

```js
let url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg';

// do a HEAD request so we don't download the whole file
fetch(url, {method: 'head'})
.then(grabFileInfo)
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.error);

function grabFileInfo(response) {
  // just in case...
  if(!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Error while fetching data');
  }
  // grab the response headers
  let headers = response.headers,
    // 'last-modified' should be in a string format
    lastModif = new Date(headers.get('last-modified'));
  return {
    // the name should be in the url
    name: response.url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1),
    type: headers.get('content-type'),
    lastModified: lastModif.getTime(),
    lastModifiedDate: lastModif,
    size: +headers.get('content-length')
  };
}
```

Or with the XHR API:

```js
var url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = grabFileInfo;
xhr.onerror = console.error;
xhr.open('HEAD', url);
xhr.send();

function grabFileInfo(xhrEvent) {
  var xhr = xhrEvent.target,
    lastModif = new Date(xhr.getResponseHeader('last-modified'));
  console.log({
    name: xhr.responseURL.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
    type: xhr.getResponseHeader('content-type'),
    lastModified: lastModif.getTime(),
    lastModifiedDate: lastModif,
    size: +xhr.getResponseHeader('content-length')
  });
}
```